# particle filter resampling question

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i need help with resampling for particle filter.

i have an array of weighted particle. and want to keep exactly the same number of particles. if i resample in a way that high weighted particles duplicate while low weighted particles are eliminated, when my tracked object (tracking using particle filter)  moves, the converged particles dont move with object and never converge again.

why does this happen?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221713/particle-filter-resampling-question/) by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 150 on 2015-11-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

maybe you need to take a look at how you are tracking the object movement. it's also possible that your weights are associated with wrong particles. check that as well.

---

Originally posted by [ja_ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/26244/ja_ros/) with karma: 31 on 2016-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0